# Xamarin.Forms (PCL) not making the call on locally hosted WCF service

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am creating a Xamarin project for a mobile app. In the Xamarin forms i am getting an Error: "System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)" .
    The service is hosted on my local machine for testing.

Comment: I don't think this is a Xamarin specific issue at all. Do you have a firewall installed? Did you disable it? Are you using the right credentials to connect? There are probably some more details in there than just 'connection refused'. It could have a dozen reasons. On the info you are providing here it is basically just guessing.

Comment: Are you testing on a emulator? Does it have wifi connected?

Comment: Yes it is running on emulator, But it did not connected to the Wifi.

Comment: How can enable Wifi on emulator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,The Xamarin requires the URL to make a http request. So i hosted my service on a server and use its url for my requests and successfully get response from service. 
For Your http request you can use the google.com to test your call. It will always return the result.